# Django Arrayfield migration to cloud sql (Postgresql) not creating the column

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

The project is already running and I tried adding an `ArrayField` to one of the models.

When `makemigrations` and `migrate` it applies all migrations but when trying insert a record to the field it says: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "<ArrayField>" of relation "<app>_<model>" does not exist`.

When checking Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) have create all columns except for this one in particular.